# xubuntu | networkmanager dependencies

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, network-manager, xfce, default-programs

I completely removed my NetworkManager with all dependencies (and I have no idea what this includes). But I managed to reinstall my NetworkManager, to edit my interface file, an no have access to the internet by LAN (I have to execute dhclient manual form terminal.).
Is there a way to reinstall just the unknown removed default packages an stuff without overwriting my customized system (personal files, thunderbird, firefox, drivers, ...)? I have read about `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal`, `ubuntu-standard` or `ubuntu-desktop`, but I'm not sure which of these fits best or if there better ways (especially for Xubuntu).

I use: 
Kernel: 5.2.21-050221-generic 
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 
Xfce 4.12 
NetworkManager version: 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1

Thanks to everybody!

Comment: Are you running Xubuntu 18.04?   XFCE 4.14 didn't come out till Xubuntu 19.10, so your XFCE version doesn't fit the XFCE version found in 18.04.  The `xubuntu-desktop` may be the package you want (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xubuntu-desktop) however it sounds like you've made an error (4.12? with parts of 4.13) or have added later packages and this may not fix your system - so checking `ubuntu-support-status` maybe worthwhile (you may no longer have a LTS system)

Comment: You are right. Sorry, transcript error. Xfce 4.12, that is what `xfce4-about`tells me. The rest should be updates from apt (and packages like nautilus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by my self.
 
Since I had stable internet I was able to use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and `reboot`. Then I did all kinds of `update`, `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade` and `install -f`. After another reboot I followed the steps under [Issues](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager). An everything seems to be as before.